# How do I convert Bitcoin to and from my local currency?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

I want to maybe try my hand in Bitcoin but I don't know of many places around here that use it so converting it would be the best route for me. Any information would be extremely helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You will need the aid of a service or individual in order to exchange [fiat currency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat_money) to and from bitcoin.

You will also need a [bitcoin wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet).

Some services offer both exchange and wallet functionality.

You may find these resources helpful:

- [How does one acquire bitcoins?](https://bitcoin.org/en/faq#how-does-one-acquire-bitcoins)
- [How to buy bitcoins](http://howtobuybitcoins.info) (Lists of services available in many countries)

  - For the United States: http://howtobuybitcoins.info/us.html
- [Trade](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Trade) (A list of many options and services)

Answer (score 0):

A good place to sell Bitcoin is coinbase. Just add your bank account. You can transfer Bitcoin to your coinbase wallet and sell them, or use coinbase as your main wallet. It's very easy to use. I hope this helps.